# Retrieving exchange rates with AJAX for currency conversion

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, html, calculator

Basically, I've been assigned the task of creating a currency conversion calculator using HTML5, JavaScript and CSS. I've managed to get as far as creating a basic calculator which allows the user to click the buttons to input their numbers with a side menu allowing them to select the 'From' and 'To' currencies respectively from a drop down menu. The next part of the task (The part I'm having problems with) requires pulling data from an external source - [From Here](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/exchange/eurofxref/html/index.en.html) - using Ajax to provide the exchange rates, I'm not too sure how to go about doing this, I basically need to have the user select their 'From' and 'To' currencies, click in their amount using the calculator's keypad and when they click '=' it returns the converted amount.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated or some links to possible solutions that I might have missed.